# rxjs/redux-observer: observable.retry to re-establish connection

Tags: javascript, rxjs5, jestjs, redux-observable

I am using [elixir phoenix websocket](https://github.com/mspanc/phoenix_socket) in an application I'm building and I have an epic that looks like this:

```
const socketObservable = Observable.create((observer: Object) => {
  const socket = new Socket(`${getWebSocketUrl()}/socket`, { params: {
    token: readSession(),
  } });

  socket.connect();

  socket.onOpen(() =>
      observer.next({ type: SOCKET_CONNECTED, socket }),
  );

  socket.onError((error) =>
      observer.error({ type: WEBSOCKET_ERROR, error }),
  );

  return () => {
    // socket.disconnect();
  };
});

const connectToSocket = (
  action$: Object,
) => action$.ofType(CONNECT_TO_SOCKET)
.switchMap(() =>
  socketObservable
    .catch((error) => Observable.of(error)),
)
.retry();

export default connectToSocket;
```

What I would like to happen is that user be notified when network connection goes away by emitting `{ type: WEBSOCKET_ERROR, error }` and have the notification removed when connection is reestablished by emitting `{ type: SOCKET_CONNECTED, socket }`. Well I got the first part working, but when re-connection happens, `{ type: SOCKET_CONNECTED, socket }` never dispatches. Using redux-saga, I was able to make this work using the following code:

```
const connectToSocket = (): Object =>
  eventChannel((emitter: (Object) => mixed) => {
    const socket = new Socket(`${getWebSocketUrl()}/socket`, { params: {
      token: readSession(),
    } });

    socket.connect();

    socket.onOpen(() => emitter({ socket }));

    socket.onError((error) => {
      emitter({ error });
    });

    return () => {
      // socket.disconnect();
    };
  });

export function* callConnectToSocket(): Generator<IOEffect, *, *> {
  const chan = yield call(connectToSocket);
  while (true) {
    const { socket, error } = yield take(chan);
    if (socket) {
      yield put({ type: SOCKET_CONNECTED, socket });
    } else {
      yield put({ error, type: WEBSOCKET_ERROR });
    }
  }
}

export function* watchConnectToSocket(): Generator<IOEffect, *, *> {
  yield takeLatest(CONNECT_TO_SOCKET, callConnectToSocket);
}
```

For the rxjs code, I thought tacking `.retry()` at the end of the chain was supposed to trigger a retry of my source observable if en error is emitted as per [documentation for rxjs Observable.retry](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry), but may be I don't really understand what `retry` was supposed to do or how to use it properly. May be someone can help to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `retry` operator to take effect, its source observable has to produce an error. And it seems that in your example the error notification never reaches `retry` as it gets swallowed by the `catch` operator which recovers from the error.

To make it work, you may try to make the `catch` operator return an observable that first emits an action and then produces an error:

```
const connectToSocket = action$ =>
    actions$.ofType(CONNECT_TO_SOCKET)
        .switchMap(() => socketObservable
            .catch(error => Observable.of(error).concat(Observable.throw(error)))
        )
        .retry();
```

**Update:**

I think it is worth mentioning that `Rx` follows the grammar `next* (complete|error)?`, meaning that `next()` calls that come after the `error()` on the same observer will have no effect. So, if the `socket` recovers from the error and executes `onOpen` callback after it has executed `onError`, the `SOCKET_CONNECTED` notification will not reach the consumer.

This could be possibly handled by either replacing `error` with `next` notifications or restarting the `socketObservable` each time an error occurs, meaning that a new `socket` instance would be created (but this is probably not what you want).

Here's a runnable code sample demonstrating how `retry` might work:

```js
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } = Redux;
const { createEpicMiddleware } = ReduxObservable;

const socketObservable = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    const t1 = setTimeout(() => observer.next({ type: "SOCKET_CONNECTED" }), 200);
    const t2 = setTimeout(() => observer.error({ type: "SOCKET_ERROR" }), 400);

    return () => {
        clearTimeout(t1);
        clearTimeout(t2);
    };
})

const connectToSocket = action$ => action$
    .do(action => console.log(action))
    .ofType("CONNECT_TO_SOCKET")
    .switchMap(() => socketObservable
        .catch(error => Rx.Observable.of(error).concat(Rx.Observable.throw(error)))
        // make 2 attempts to re-connect, i.e. restart socketObservable
        .retry(2)
    )
    // recover in case if both attempts to reconnect have failed
    .retry();

const store = createStore(
    (state, action) => state,
    applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(connectToSocket)));

// dispatch CONNECT_TO_SOCKET two times
Rx.Observable.interval(2000)
    .take(2)
    .subscribe(x => store.dispatch({ type: "CONNECT_TO_SOCKET" }));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.4.2/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@3.7.2/dist/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux-observable@0.14.1/dist/redux-observable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergey Karavaev. I have tried your suggestion and it did not work.

Comment: Just want to clarify: do you want your `retry` to re-establish a socket connection or just recover from the error? In the first case you may try to move `retry` call to the inner observable, immediately after the `catch`.

Comment: I've got another idea: do you expect your `socketObservable` to produce `SOCKET_CONNECTED` notification after it has produced `WEBSOCKET_ERROR`? I.e. `onOpen` callback may be called even after `onError` has been called on the same `socket` instance? If so, then it's not possible as `Rx` does not allow that. `Rx` follows the grammar: `next* (complete|error)?`, meaning that no other notification can go after the `error` within the same stream. So, either you go with `next` notifications only (as you eventually did) or re-create `socketObservable` after the `error` has been received.

Comment: `@Sergey Karavaev` you are right. Moving `retry` into the inner observable and concatenating `Observer.throw` did the job. I really needed to throw the error so I could execute some code inside `Observable.do` for the happy path. Actually retrying creates a new socket connection but that is no problem because the former connection is closed automatically. Thanks for giving your time. I'm truly grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally gave up on throwing an error when connection is dropped and changed this line `observer.error({ type: WEBSOCKET_ERROR, error })` to `observer.next({ type: WEBSOCKET_ERROR, error })`. But I'm still wondering what I was doing wrong with `retry`. Any help with the original code will be greatly appreciated.